# Adding isExists function to WebElement

Tags: java, selenium

I want to extends selenium and implement something like this:

```
public class IsExistsWebElement extends WebElement {

    public boolean isExists() {
        try {
            this.getText();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And then using it like this (using page factory):

```
public class HomePage{

    @FindBy(class = "button")
    private IsExistsWebElement button;

    public HomePage(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public boolean isButtonExists() {
        return this.button.isExists();
    }
}
```

What is the best way to implement something like this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for custom implementation then you have to create a new framework on top of selenium and have to write your own implementation for most of the things.

For example `RemoteWebElement`class implements the `WebElement` interface. But its not simple to write just below code and have the access as we do for WebElement

e.g. `IsExistsWebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("a"));`

```
class IsExistsWebElement extends RemoteWebElement {
    public boolean isExists() {
        try {
            this.getText();
            return true;
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are looking for new framework on top of selenium and can afford the time(may be 3,6,9.. months depends on resources) and cost then happily go for it.

OR

Looking for managing the wait in generic way in page object model then

1. Create a BasePage class
2. Initiate explicit wait in constructor
3. Create wait methods for presence, visibility and so on
4. Extend this BasePage class in your other page class

e.g

```
public BasePage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TIMEOUT, POLLING);
    PageFactory.initElements(new AjaxElementLocatorFactory(driver, TIMEOUT), this);
}


public void waitForElementReady(WebElement element) {
    try {
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element));
    } catch (TimeoutException exception) {
        System.out.println("Element didn't find in given time");
    }
}
```